# Cannot understand the behaviour of C# compiler while instantiating a class thru interface

Tags: c#

I have a class that implements an interface. The interface is

```
public interface IRiskFactory
{
   void StartService();
   void StopService();
}
```

The class that implements the interface is

```
public class RiskFactoryService : IRiskFactory
{
}
```

Now I have a console application and one window service.

From the console application if I write the following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IRiskFactory objIRiskFactory = new RiskFactoryService();
    objIRiskFactory.StartService();
    Console.ReadLine();
    objIRiskFactory.StopService();
}
```

It is working fine. However, when I mwrite the same piece of code in Window service

```
public partial class RiskFactoryService : ServiceBase
{
    IRiskFactory objIRiskFactory = null;
    public RiskFactoryService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objIRiskFactory = new RiskFactoryService(); <- ERROR
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        objIRiskFactory.StartService();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the service
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        objIRiskFactory.StopService();
    }
}
```

It throws error: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'RiskFactoryService' to 'IRiskFactory'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

When I type cast to the interface type, it started working

```
objIRiskFactory = (IRiskFactory)new RiskFactoryService();
```

My question is why so?

Comment: Maybe I am overlooking something but are you not getting a StackOverflowException from creation of RiskFactoryService....the parameterless constructor calls itself recursively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two thoughts occur:

- if you are using `partial` to have the service / interface parts of the type in separate files (since the code mentions `partial` and doesn't seem to implement the interface itself) are the namespaces correct? With `partial` classes it is perilously easy to accidentally end up creating two types rather than one type
- is `IRiskFactory` suffering from resolution issues (perhaps from having a referenced dll and a local copy)? i.e. is all the code talking about the *same* `IRiskFactory` ?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldnt your windows service class actually implement service like below ...

```
public partial class RiskFactoryService : ServiceBase  , IRiskFactory
{
}
```

and why are you creating RiskFactoryService in constructor of RiskFactoryService, i think this will give stack overflow error !! You can simply call , this.StartService()...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in this case RiskFactoryService is referring to the partial class definition RiskFactoryService : ServiceBase which does not implement IRiskFactory (did you mean that class to be the same as the RiskFactoryService class that does implement IRiskFactory? - if so that class definition should probably be marked partial as well).

A more pressing problem I see is that you are recursively calling the constructor for the RiskFactoryService class inside itself. This means that every time you try to instantiate a RiskFactoryService the stack will overflow.